# How to Run selected code/line in Jupyter notebook of DataSpell or PyCharm

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, google-colaboratory, dataspell

Is there anyway to run only selected code/line in Jupyter notebook of DataSpell or Pycharm?

In Google Colab, you have the option to run only selected code/line by pressing Ctrl + Shift + Enter. Here I just highlighted only "flights" and run, so it showed the dataframe, not the result of "1+1"
[See in Google Colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSxZn.png)